# I am trying to pass an array of string pointers to a c funtion from NASM assembly

Tags: c, linux, nasm

So I’m very new to assembly and for my class I’m supposed to pass an array of string pointers to a C function to display them you can ignore validate. As you can see when I run it in GDB I can see the string output. Is it in the wrong place? Did I do something wrong with my pointer I call the display function after the JLE instruction. I am also running this on WSL.

error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e32540 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fa7c80 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=640) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4375
4375    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff7e32540 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fa7c80 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=640) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4375
#1  0x00007ffff7e32a49 in tcache_init () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3245
#2  0x00007ffff7e3325e in tcache_init () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3241
#3  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3306
#4  0x00007ffff7e0cc24 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7fa8780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ./libio/filedoalloc.c:101
#5  0x00007ffff7e1bd60 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7fa8780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#6  0x00007ffff7e1afe0 in _IO_new_file_overflow (f=0x7ffff7fa8780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at ./libio/fileops.c:744
#7  0x00007ffff7e19755 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (n=22, data=<optimized out>, f=<optimized out>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#8  _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7fa8780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=22) at ./libio/fileops.c:1196
#9  0x00007ffff7e0ef9c in __GI__IO_puts (str=0x404058 "This is the original.\n") at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#10 0x0000000000401307 in display ()
#11 0x00000000004011bb in loop ()
#12 0x00007ffff7db7d90 in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x401180 <main>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdf18) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#13 0x00007ffff7db7e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x401180 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf18, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdf08)
at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#14 0x00000000004010b5 in _start ()
```

NASM code:

```
;Extern ceasar ;calling my project3
;All funcitons below are writen in C
;Extern read_message ;read message from user
Extern display ;display the strings
;Extern decrypt ;decypt function
extern freeUp ;free memory
extern printf
extern validate
extern fprintf

section .data
defaultMessage db "This is the original.", 10, 0
len_Mess equ $-defaultMessage
fmtpf db "%d", 10, 0

section .bss
array resq 10


section .text

global main

main:

mov r8, 64
mov r9, 0
xor r10,r10
mov r11, 10
loop:

mov qword[array + r10], defaultMessage
add r10, r8
add r9, 1
cmp r9, r11
JLE loop
mov rdi, array
call display
call validate
mov [array], rax


exit:
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, [array]
call freeUp
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```

c code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* validate(){
int buffer = 256;
int pos = 0;
    char* cmd = malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
    
    int cha;
        int cont = 1;
    
        while(cont == 1){
                cha = fgetc(stdin);
    
                if(cha == EOF || cha == '\n'){
                        cmd[pos] = '\0';
                        cont = 0;
                }
                else{
                        cmd[pos] = cha;
                }
    
                pos++;
    
                if(pos >= buffer){
                        buffer += 256;
                        cmd = realloc(cmd, buffer);
    
                }
        }
    
        return cmd;

}
void display(char** Array){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                printf("%s\n", Array[i]);
        }
        return;
}

void freeUp(char* msg){
free(msg);
}
```

I am trying to pass the array from assembly to C and have it print all the strings in the array.

Comment: All the compilers I use gives compilation errors for your backslashes, like on the first line: `\#include \<stdio.h\>` which should have been `#include <stdio.h>` and `void display(char\*\* Array)` which should have been `void display(char** Array)`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: You are incrementing array pointer (`r10`) by 64 *bytes*, not bits. It should be `mov r8, 8`. Or increment it by 1 and use scale factor 8: `mov qword[array + r10*8]`

Comment: Stack overflow added the slashes i dont have those in the actual program